# Python Numpy mask NaN not working

Tags: python, numpy

I'm simply trying to use a masked array to filter out some `nan`entries.

```
import numpy as np
# x = [nan, -0.35, nan]
x = np.ma.masked_equal(x, np.nan)
print x
```

This outputs the following:

```
masked_array(data = [        nan -0.33557216         nan],
         mask = False,
   fill_value = nan)
```

Calling `np.isnan()` on `x` returns the correct boolean array, but the mask just doesn't seem to work. Why would my mask not be working as I expect?

Comment: You should probably use [`np.ma.masked_invalid()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html#numpy.ma.masked_invalid).

Comment: that works, thanks. if you post an answer I can close this question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`np.ma.masked_invalid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = [np.nan, 3.14, np.nan]
mx = np.ma.masked_invalid(x)

print(repr(mx))
# masked_array(data = [-- 3.14 --],
#              mask = [ True False  True],
#        fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Alternatively, use `np.isnan(x)` as the `mask=` parameter to `np.ma.masked_array`:

```
print(repr(np.ma.masked_array(x, np.isnan(x))))
# masked_array(data = [-- 3.14 --],
#              mask = [ True False  True],
#        fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Why doesn't your original approach work? Because, rather counterintuitively, `NaN` is not equal to `NaN`!

```
print(np.nan == np.nan)
# False
```

This is actually [part of the IEEE-754 definition of `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/1461210)

Answer (score 7):

Here is another alternative without using mask:

```
import numpy as np
#x = [nan, -0.35, nan]
xmask=x[np.logical_not(np.isnan(x))]
print(xmask)
```

Result:

`array([-0.35])`

Comment: And for anyone wondering, `np.logical_not` is needed here instead of the built-in `not` because the latter does not broadcast.

Comment: `np.isnan()` returns a boolean array, and as such using `x[~np.isnan(x)]` would suffice. `np.logical_not()` is useful for non-boolean array use-cases.